SLG Fault calculation at Bus 3 (33kV) for three winding transformer- see image below
Can someone please help with solving Single Line to Ground fault current at the Bus3 of the below single line diagram, single line parameters are as below:
Grid:
3Ph Fault current 50kA, X/R =14
1Ph Fault Current 50kA, X/R =14
TF1:
285/142.5/42.5 MVA, 330/33/33 kV, Yn0d1d1
Positive sequence impedance = Negative Sequence =  Zps = 14%, Zpt = 14%, Zst = 28%, X/R =57
Zero Sequence  is same as Positive sequence impedance.
TF2 (Aux TF datasheet and FAT attached):
33/0.436/0.114 kV, 0.5MVA, Ynynd
Appreciate your help with hand calculation if possible.



